# how to alert something when button with a length is click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

I have this button

```
<div class="bigbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="bigboxinput">
    <div class="smallbox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="smallboxinput1">
        <button class="addinput">Add another input</button>
    </div>   
</div>
<button class="addbigbox">Add another bigbox</button>
```

when I click that button I want to alert something like "hello" using javascript

```
<script> 
var n = $('.addmore').length + 1;
$('.addmore').click(function(){  //I dont know what to do here
alert('Hello');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain little more what you want to achieve

Comment: I already updated the question above

Comment: supposedly I have a lot of buttons whenever I add one or more(button) so n in class="addmore' + n + '" ..n supposedly n=1, n=2, n=3  so on and so forth

Comment: Can you tell what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/cxu429e7/8/

I assumed html like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="bigbox">
    <div class="smallbox">
      <input type="text" />
      <button class="addinput">Add an input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="addbigbox">Add a bigbox</button>
</div>
```

And here's the code:

```
$('.addbigbox').click(function() {
  var target = $('<button>')
      .addClass('addinput')
      .html('add an input');
  $(this)
    .before(
    $('<div>')
    .addClass('bigbox')
    .append(
      $('<input>')
      .attr('type','text')
    )
    .append(
      target
    )
  )
  addInput(target);
});
var addInput = function(target){
  target.click( function() {
    $(this)
      .before(
      $('<input>')
      .attr('type','text')
    )
  });
};
addInput($('.addinput'));
```

Comment: when I click the button addmore it creates another div supposedly taget2 with a new button addmore thats why I have addmore'+n+' <- when I click this i want to add input tag inside target2

Comment: Ah, I see.  It's recursive, then, with multiple "add more"s inside each container. Ok, let me see....

Comment: I updated my html above :D

Comment: I updated the code.  I leave off 'id's whenever possible.  In this case, I would add elements relative to the button.

Comment: when I add another input in second big box it doesnt work

Comment: When you dynamically add an 'addinput', you've got to also add the click event.

Comment: Ugh - I've got to edit it a little more

Comment: You're too kind.  It should be fixed now.  Cheers.

Comment: one more thing when I click the add an input button sometimes it will add 2 to 3 input it should be only 1 once i click the button add an input

Comment: sir just this one I want to print "hello" when i click this button
    <button type="button" class="addmore'+ n +'" >Add '</button>

Comment: Just add an alert in the bottom of each click.  I updated the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/cxu429e7/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button.addinput').on('click', function(){
   var ThisIt = $(this);
   var n = $('input[type=text]').length + 1;
   $('<input value="input '+n+'" type="text">').insertBefore(ThisIt);
});
```

> **Note:** be sure to include jquery

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cxu429e7/3/)

you can use the same way for .addbigbox

Comment: when I add another bigbox, all input display in first bigbox only

Comment: @user101 something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/cxu429e7/5/

Comment: IT WORKS NOW THANKS A LOT, YOU GUYS IS A GENIUS :D

Comment: @user101  but keep in mind that the code may need more efforts from you to get it to work as you need .. you will find more things to modify it up to your need . but in all ways I think you got more points from that code . Good Luck :)

Comment: I will, YES and thanks to you guys :D